# Best way to check for data updates on webserver

Tags: ios, database, swift, webserver

I have an application which uses the data from web server. When you first launch the app, it downloads the data and then work with it. But what if the data on web site was changed. How can I know from the application that the data was changed, and if so, what data should I download?

My first idea was each time when you run the application to check the number of entries in the local database on your phone and the number of entries on web server, and if they are not equal, delete all data in local database and then download all data again. But I think that it will take more time than if the application just loads 5-10 needed records instead of all data.

The second idea was when the information on the site changes, website somehow has to inform the application to load some records. But I don’t know if it is possible to do(

Another idea was to compare the id of the last entry in the application database with last id on website. And if they are not equal download the information from the next id.

Are there any suggestions how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi. Need to save the data and the timestamp in the local DB. Then, e.g. in re-launch the app, ask the server about a new data - just send the timestamp of a last data update. If the server tells - need to update, you invoke the data update url. The server should implement this functionality - checking new data by timestamp.

Comment: You can use push notifications to advise your app that there is new data.

Comment: @Mozilla your solution seems to be ok, i'll try it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you have any database or web services but my suggestion is parsing data from the web with JSON or XML.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/

this class reference is will be clear for you.

Also in my opinion, if you are new in swift and want to choose easy way for this operation search for iOS package managers.

If you want to use a package manager for your project, e.g **Pod**

> https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire

would be a good startig point.

> Alamofire is an HTTP networking library written in Swift.

Hope to helped you